# Error using named pipes with PowerShell Remoting

Tags: powershell, pipe, named-pipes, remoting

I created a script to use named pipes asynchronously from PowerShell and it's working fine from PowerShell ISE. You can see the client and server code in my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338421/asynchronous-named-pipes-in-powershell-using-callbacks).

My final goal is to use it from PowerShell remoting, but when I run it like that I get an Exception "Access to the path is denied" when the client tries to connect (NamedPipeClientStream.Connect).

Some information:

- The client script below should be able to run without the server code running. The Client should wait for three seconds for the specified named pipe to be created, and fail if the pipe is not created. This is the expected behavior: "Failed to connect client to pipe testPipe within 3 seconds"
- The code behaves as expected when executed on the same machine locally from PowerShell ISE with the same account I am using for the remote connection when calling Invoke-Command, but when executed remotely, I get the "Access to the path is denied" error, as if the client didn't have permissions to even attempt to use named pipes.
- The account is part of the Administrators group

Code:

```
Function Send-PipeMessage($serverIP, $pipeName, $message, $timeoutSeconds=300)
{
    $PipeDir  = [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::Out
    $PipeOpt  = [System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions]::Asynchronous
    $success  = $false

    try
    {
        $pipeClient = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream($serverIP, $pipeName, $PipeDir, $PipeOpt)
        $sw = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($pipeClient)

        $endDate = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($timeoutSeconds)

        Write-Host "Trying to connect to a pipe named $pipeName for $timeoutSeconds seconds"

        while(! $pipeClient.IsConnected -and ($endDate -gt (Get-Date)))
        {
            try
            {
                $pipeClient.Connect(1000)
            }
            catch [TimeoutException]
            {}
        }

        if (! $pipeClient.IsConnected)
        {
            throw "Failed to connect client to pipe $pipeName within $timeoutSeconds seconds"
        }
        else
        {
            $sw.AutoFlush = $true
            $sw.WriteLine($message)
            $success = $true
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if ($sw)
            {
                $sw.Dispose()
                $sw = $null
            }
            if ($pipeClient)
            {
                $pipeClient.Dispose()
                $pipeClient = $null
            }
        }
        catch {}
    }

    return $success
}

Send-PipeMessage '.' 'testPipe' 'test message' 3
```

Comment: You are not saying how you are running this. Meaning an Explicit or Implicit remoting session. Lastly, you cannot use local variables in a remoting session without the proper scope. See the help files on About_Scopes, specifically the $Using option.'Example 5: Using a Local Variable in a Remote Command'

Comment: Thanks, I am using PowerShell Remoting explicitly. Also, when I run remotely, all the code is sent in the script block, so all variables are defined in the remote computer. This is the same issue described here with no solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7aaf18e2-f8ae-4590-979a-44af62b73d5b